# Get receive custom header in Laravel with SwiftMessage from reply E-mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5

I send E-mail with Mailable on laravel and I add custom header with `SwiftMessage` .
when I send E-mail,Laravel send mail with my custom header but problem is when 
reply my email from return E-mail does not exist my custom header.
This is my code:

```
public function build()
{
    $this->view('sendmail')->with('text',  $this->data);
    $this->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
        $message->getHeaders()
            ->addTextHeader('my_header', 'my_header_value');
    });
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by **"when reply my email from return E-mail"**?

Comment: In my script I want to send and receive email  I want to when I send email for customer and customer reply to my email I read my custom header

Answer (score 1):

Including custom headers in the reply email is beyond your control - it's up to the email client from which the reply is being sent.